# Random do not use rand() function in C

Tags: c, random, time

I need to generate a random number without using the random function. I made that in Java using `system.nanotime` but I can't in C.  How can I do that?

Comment: Fetch random bytes from `/dev/urandom`? It might help if you explained why you're unable to use `random()`....

Comment: `time() ^ getpid()` is a start.  What is your OS?, How random does it need to be?  Perhaps posting your "I made that in Java using system.nanotime" to get an idea of what you want?  Do you need truly random or pseudo-random OK?

Comment: My os is windows,ı need pseudo-random

Comment: Maybe you should use Windows own [`CryptGenRandom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  There were buggy versions in some (old) incarnations of Windows (see [The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/11/13/windows_random_number_gen_flawed/), so be cautious, but using it would save you a good deal of hassle.  OTOH, it may be over the top for what  you need; it is cryptographically random and you may not need that much randomness (and if a nanosecond counter is sufficiently random, your probably do not need cryptographic randomness).

Comment: There are hundreds of PRNG algorithms. Pick one and implement your own. Start with something simple, like Marsaglia XorShift.

Comment: `system.nanotime` isn't a random number generator. It gets you the current time.

Comment: yes,you are right but it returns an unpredictable result, I need such a function @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: "random" means "unpredictable". What are you actually looking for?

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "a random number". There are only sequences of numbers with a random distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the  standard header: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono.

Also, Unix systems have special `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` files that you could make use of with calls to `int system(const char *string)`. For example you could write some random bytes from `/dev/urandom` to a file (i.e. `system("cat /dev/urandom | head -n 1 > random_bytes.bin");` and read the random data from `random_bytes.bin`.

See:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random

Answer (score -1):

you can add any random generator library to your code.

[Meresenne twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/980409/mt19937int.c) is a great one

[Here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html) you can find a lot of varites of `.c .cpp .h` files

Comment: @chux sry , yep it is